# Extension of maximal solutions of a Ordinary differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I've tried to do this problem but I'm struggling right now.
Any help would be highly appreciated.

"Prove that if we define $f: \mathbb{R}^2\,\to\, \mathbb{R}$ a continuous and locally lipschitz function with respect to $x$. Let $x_{max}: \, \left( a,b \right)\to\mathbb{R}$ be the maximal solution to the Cauchy problem (IVP). Then:

- if $b\lt\infty$ we have that $\left|x_{max}(t)\right|\to \infty$ when $t \to b^-$
- if $-\infty\lt a$ we have that $\left|x_{max}(t)\right|\to \infty$ when $t \to a^+$

Edit:
Attempt to make the proof:

Note that since we have that $X_{max}\notin K\, ,$ for all $Ks\,$ Compacts of $\mathbb{R}^2$ and $\forall t \in \left( b-\epsilon , b\right)$.

Now let's define $K'=\left[ a,b\right]$x$\left[ n,n\right]$, now with $n\to \infty$ and $x_{max} \notin K'$ then: $x_{max} \to \infty$.

Is this right?

Thanks for the assistance

Comment: Can you use a theorem like "The maximal solution leaves every compact set inside the domain of $f$"?

Comment: @LutzLehmann yes I can use that theorem

Comment: Then use boxes/cylinders over $[a,b]$ with increasing radius in $x$ direction. The solution can not leave these boxes on the time sides.

Comment: @LutzLehmann Can you please check if the attempt of proof that I did in the edit is right?

Comment: You have all the correct formulas, but the argument that you make with them is not very comprehensible. For the compact set $K_n=[a,b]\times[n,n]$ there has to be some $ϵ_n$ with $x(t)\not\in K_n$ for infinitely many $t\in(b−ϵ_n,b)$. From this one concludes the unboundedness of $x(t)$.